# Find Maclaurin polynomial of degree $5$ to $f(x$).

Tags: taylor-expansion

**Problem:**

Find Maclaurin polynomial of degree $5$ to $f(x)$.

$$f(x) = xe^{-2x^{2}}$$

**Attempted Solution:**

[image]

**Question:**

I got the answer:
$$ P_{5} = x $$

The correct answer should be:
$$ P_{5} = x - 2x^{3} + 2x^{5}$$

So, my question is what I am doing wrong?
If $x = 0$, won’t the $(0 + 0)x^2$ disappear when multiplying with $0$?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because key textual information is contained in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only found the second degree Maclaurin polynomial $P_2$ (which happens to be equal to $P_1$). You need to take another three derivatives to find the remaining terms of $P_5$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is to compute a second order Taylor polynomial when you were requested to compute a fifth order one.

Answer (score 0):

Mac Laurin polynomial means the expansion is centered at $x = 0$. You stopped too early.

Consider the series in its general expansion around a generic point $z$:

$$x e^{-2x^2} \sim e^{-2 z^2} z-e^{-2 z^2} \left(4 z^2-1\right) (x-z)+2 e^{-2 z^2} z \left(4 z^2-3\right) (x-z)^2-\frac{2}{3} \left(e^{-2 z^2} \left(16 z^4-24 z^2+3\right)\right) (x-z)^3+\frac{2}{3} e^{-2 z^2} z \left(16 z^4-40 z^2+15\right) (x-z)^4-\frac{2}{15} \left(e^{-2 z^2} \left(64 z^6-240 z^4+180 z^2-15\right)\right) (x-z)^5+O\left((x-z)^6\right)$$

Whn $z = 0$ this all reduces to

$$x e^{-2x^2} \sim x-2 x^3+2 x^5+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Whence your result.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this uses a power series you already know: $$e^t=1+t+\frac12t^2+\frac13t^3+\dots$$

With $t=-2x^2$ this gives$$xe^{-2x^2}=x(1+(-2x^2)+\frac12(-2x^2)^2+\frac16(-2x^2)^3\dots)=x-2x^3+2x^5+\dots$$